# How to get "xmlns:XXX" attribute if set setNamespaceAware(true) in SAX?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, saxparser

Here is my code:

```
path = wsdlPath;
SAXParserFactory saxfac = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
saxfac.setNamespaceAware(true);
saxfac.setXIncludeAware(true);
saxfac.setValidating(false);
SAXParser saxParser = saxfac.newSAXParser();
saxParser.parse(wsdlPath, this);
```

After Setting `setNamespaceAware=true`, I can't get the `xmlns:XXX` attributes in parameter `attributes` of method `public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)`.

for the following node:

```
<definitions name="Service1"
    targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/service"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/">
```

I just get `name` and `targetNamespace` attribute. `xmlns`, `xmlns:wsdl`, `xmlns:mime`, `xmlns:http` and `xmlns:tns` are in the `attributes` parameter. But they are not accessible.

Is there any way to use `setNamespaceAware=true` and get all attributes of a node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When your XML parser is XML Namespace aware, then you should not *need* access to those properties, as they only define the short names for namespaces used in your XML.

In that case you always refer to the name spaces using their full name (e.g. `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/`) and can ignore what short name they are aliased to in the XML (e.g. `wsdl`).

The fact that SAX doesn't provide those values is documented on the [`Attributes` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html):

> It will [...] not contain attributes used as Namespace declarations (`xmlns*`) unless the `http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes` feature is set to `true` (it is `false` by default).

So using [`saxfac.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes", true)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#setFeature%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) should help you get to those values.

Comment: I tried using this advice and found that I also had to do the following: `saxfac.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);`

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to get the namespace declarations is from the startPrefixMapping event:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startPrefixMapping(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)